# Retrieving Multiple Images from phpmyadmin dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a set of Multiple choice questions stored in phpmyadmin. I need to retrieve an image along with each question and answers. In other words, when the users start the test or click on the "next question" button, they need to see not only the question and answers, but also the image related to that question. I have already saved the images in Blob format in the database, but have problem for retrieving them dynamically. Would appreciate it if somebody helps me

Here is part of the code:

```
$singleSQL = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        $question_id = $row['question_id'];
        $q = '<h2><i>'.$thisQuestion.'</i></h2>';

        $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");
        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
            $answer = $row2['answer'];
            $correct = $row2['correct'];
            $answers .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'"><b>'.$answer.'</b></label> 
            <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />
            ';  
        }

        $sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM quiz_takers");
        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)){
        $name = $row3['username'];
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for displaying the blob images:

```
$image = $row['image'];
echo '<img src="data:image/type;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" />';
```

replacing `image/type` with `image/jpeg` or whatever type the images are.

Comment: The problem is that I need to match a different image with a question. If I use a code like that, I have the same static image for all the questions

Comment: Does each question have an image associated with it or is the image selected at random?

Comment: Each question has a specific image associated with it. i have two different tables for the questions and images, and have tried to link them to each other through the question_id

Comment: So all you need to do is query the image that has the given question_id and display it for that question using the code I gave above.

Comment: No result :(                                                $image_sql = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM media WHERE question_id= 1");
         while ($row4 = mysql_fetch_array ($image_sql)) {
   $image = $row4['images'];
   echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($image).'" />';
    
   }

Comment: Your query doesn't return anything or it fails to output the image(s)?

Comment: it returns Parse error: Syntax error            along with an empty, broken image space

Comment: just Parse error: Syntax Error.        The code is a bit complex, i guess i need to modify it in several places

Comment: Put this line `error_reporting(E_ALL);`at the beginning of your code and see if you get more info about the error